# jQuery active text color not changing

Tags: jquery, css

I am having trouble getting my active tab to have a blue background and white text, while still having my hover to work. And advice would be appreciated. It seems simple but I've been struggling with it for a couple days.

Thanks.

```
jQuery:
$('nav #secondary li').on('click',function(){
    $('nav #secondary li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

CSS:
nav #secondary li:hover, .active {
    background-color:#1F4B80;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XBfMV/213/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the selector `nav #secondary li` (which is setting the `color` to `#1F4B80`) has a [higher specificity calculation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the selector `.active`.

Increase the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of `.active` to something like `nav #secondary li.active`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xzp8dzy2/)

```
nav #secondary li:hover,
nav #secondary li.active {
    background-color: #1F4B80;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also just decrease the specificity of the selectors. Either would work.

For what it's worth, here are the [specificity calculations](http://specificity.keegan.st/) of each of the selectors:

- `nav #secondary li` - 102
- `nav #secondary li.active` - 112
- `.active` - 10 (which is why it was being overridden)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about specificity calculations.